# Integral reducing to infinite summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I am looking to evaluate the integral
$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\lfloor 1 - \log_2(1 - x) \rfloor}$$
Investigating the [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+dx+%2F+floor%281+-+log_2%281+-+x%29%29+from+0+to+1) of the function, I found that the area under the curve equaled
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n \cdot 2^n}$$
I checked the series on my calculator and found that it was equal to $\ln 2$. I also found it on Wikipedia under "Natural logarithm of 2" and "Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe formula", on [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+n+%3D+1+to+infinity+of+1%2F%28n+*+2%5En%29) and on [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalLogarithmof2.html). However, none of them gave a derivation.

How can I find the value of the infinite sum? Alternatively, how else can I evaluate the integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n\cdot 2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n-1}}{2^n}\,dx =\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{2-x}=\log 2.$$